# Working with tables

Tags: c#, xna

I'm making a small game using XNA, but it is cumbersome to effectively type-in the stats to all the entities in the game.

I was thinking that it would be much simpler to save the required information in a separate file with a table-format and use that instead.

I have looked into reading Excel tables with C# but it seems to be overly complex.
Is there any other table-format file types that let me easily edit the contents of the file and also read the contents using C# without too much hassle??
Basically, is there any other simple alternative to Excel? I just need the simplest table files to save some text in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are comfortable using Excel try exporting to a .CSV (Comma Seperate Value) file. The literal string will look like below.

```
row1col1,row1col2\nrow2col1,row2col2\nrow3col1,row3col2
```

The format is incredibly simple. Each row is on a separate line (separated by "\n") and the columns within a line are separated by commas. Very easy to parse just iterate though the lines and split on the commas.

```
while ((row = tr.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    row.split(",")[0] //first column 
    row.split(",")[1] //second column 
    row.split(",")[2] //ect...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)  is probably the simplest format to store table data, Excel can save data in it. There is no built in classes to read data from CSV as far as I know.

You may also consider XML or JSON to store data if you want some more structured data. Both have built in classes to serialize objects to/from.

Answer (score 1):

This may be overkill, but SQLlite might be worth looking into if you want expand-ability and maintainability. It is an easy setup and learning SQL will be useful in many applications.

This is a good tutorial to get you started:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/157830-using-sqlite-with-c%23/

I understand if this isn't exactly what you were looking for, but I wanted to give you a broader range of options. If you are going for absolute simplicity go with CSV or XML like Alexei said.

Edit: If necessary there is a C# SQLlite version for managed environments(XBOX,WP7)  http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/47127/282261.aspx